# Cant manage to drag and drop picture

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, drag-and-drop, frontend

I am at a loss here. While the code should work, and console logs on the beginning of the drag and drop script work. after the loop in the drag and drop script they stop.

Script to fetch from mock API

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 const fetchData = async() => {
 const response = await fetch('https://n161.tech/api/dummyapi/user?limit=5&page=1');
 const data = await response.json();
//  items = JSON.stringify(data);
 console.log(data);
 div = document.getElementById('userData');
    for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
        var str ='<div>'+data.data[i].id +' '+data.data[i].firstName +' '+ data.data[i].lastName+ '</div>';
        str +='<img id ="'+data.data[i].id+'" draggable= "true" onMouseDown=(event) '+data.data[i].id +'" class="avatar"  src="'+data.data[i].image+'" alt="'+data.data[i].firstName + data.data[i].lastName+'">';
        div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', str );

    }

  var forceStyle = document.getElementById('userData');
  forceStyle.setAttribute('style', 'border:2px black; margin:10%;');



 }




fetchData();



    });
```

The drag and drop script

```
    let pictureHolder = document.getElementById("userData");

    let dropContainer = document.getElementById("left");

    let avatar = document.getElementsByClassName("avatar");

    let mouseOffset = {x: 0, y: 0};

    let isMouseDown = false;
    addAvatrListeners(avatar);
    function addAvatrListeners(avatar){
        console.log(avatar);

        for(let i = 0; i < avatar.length; i++){
            let item = avatar[i];
            console.log(item);
            item.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
                onMouseDown(e, item);
            });

            document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", (e)=> {
                onMouseMove(e, item);
            });

            item.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
                onMouseUp(e, item);
            });
        }
    }





function onMouseDown(e, item){
    console.log('works');
    isMouseDown = true;
    mouseOffset = {x: item.offsetLeft - e.clientX, y: item.offsetTop - e.clientY};

   item.style.backgroundColor = "aquamarine";

}

function onMouseMove(e, item){
    e.preventDefault();

    if(isMouseDown){

       item.style.left = e.clientX + mouseOffset.x + "px";
       item.style.top = e.clientY + mouseOffset.y + "px"; 
    }
}
function onMouseUp(e, item){
    isMouseDown = false;
    item.style.backgroundColor = "black";

}
```

the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pictures&users</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <!-- <script scr="fetch.js"></script> -->
    <script src="fetch.js"></script>
    <script src="dragAndDrop.js"></script>




</head>
<body>
        <div class="" id="container">


                <div id="left" onMouseUp=(event) class="section"></div>  
                <div class="section scroll-div box right"  id="userData"></div> 

              </div>

</body>
</html>
```

issues found:
drag and drop script is called first for some reason.(Probably because its asynchronous)
Events are not recognized.
Events just wont work.
offsetLeft is undefined.

I'll appreciate input, thanks in advance!